# Flutter: Access data from InheritedWidgets without context?

Tags: dart, flutter, inherited-widget

I see that I can access InheritedWidgets inside the `build()` method like this: `final inheritedWidget = ChronoApp.of(context);` but what if I want to access it somewhere else, say in `initState()` which has no context. How would I do this?

Answer (score 9):

What I found to work for me is getting the parent context and using it in the `didChangeDependencies()` function that is called after initState. Like this

```
@override
  // TODO: implement context
  BuildContext get context => super.context;

@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    bloc = LoginBlocProvider.of(context);
    bloc.isAuthenticated.listen((bool value) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });

      if (value) {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()
        ));
      }
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

From de didChangeDependencies() docs:

> This method is also called immediately after initState. It is safe to
>   call BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType from this method.

I'm still trying to fully understand this feature but this is what worked for me

Answer (score 5):

According to this docs `context` should be available in `initState` using the `context` getter.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/context.html

> The framework associates State objects with a BuildContext after creating them with StatefulWidget.createState and before calling initState.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I think I used this myself somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `didChangeDependencies()` is the better place as its called after the initState() and you will get the context there.

Comment: I think you are right. `didChangeDependencies` can be called more than once though.